# Missing `]' shell error

Tags: shell-script

```
while true

do

echo "Enter the number"

read Num

while[$Num -lt 1 || $Num -gt 50]


do

echo "Please enter a new number "

read Num

done
```

Comment: Where is second `done`?

Comment: And you need a space in between `while` and `[`. There are tons of shell script examples online.

Comment: You also need two spaces between `[` and `$Num` and `50` and  `]`.

Comment: As it's written, this would give a "command not found" for `while[`, or the whole `while[...]`, or an error about the glob not matching, so the error message in the title and the code in the script don't even match.

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors and warnings. Also please use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) in these kind of situations.

**Errors:**

1. Space between `while` and `[`.
2. Space after `[` and before `]`.
3. Disaster because there is no `done`, may be you forgot or you just pasted half of your code.
4. Use `[ a ] || [ b ]` instead of `[ a || b ]`.

**Warnings:**

1. You should use `read -r` instead of `read`.
2. Double quote variable names otherwise this will not work if they have special characters.

Correct Code:

```
while true
do
    echo "Enter the number"
    read -r Num
    while [ "$Num" -lt 1 ] || [ "$Num" -gt 50 ]
    do
        echo "Please enter a new number "
        read -r Num
    done
done
```